# how to debug html page in vs2002

Tags: javascript, .net, html, debugging

I have a .net application that has a page with frame on it showing an html page.

Now this html page is not rendering properly and is showing some error. It contains some java script code and some session variable problem in the same is making that page to generate error.

```
/abc.com/ticker_change.html Last-Modified: Fri, 31 Dec 2010 19:05:49 GMT Accept-Ranges: bytes ETag: "a090fbbc1da9cb1:180b" Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET set-cookie: SMSESSION=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; path=/; domain=.abc.com Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 05:39:22 GMT
```

Above is some blah blah code that is generating on that page. The problem is **I am unable to debug the HTM page even after applying `debugger`**.

Can someone explain how to debug the script on html page.

Comment: which browser are you using while debuging?

Comment: look at link http://forums.asp.net/t/289855.aspx/1

Comment: i am able to debug .cs pages but not the html pages

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few days ago.

Check this link, it should help you out.

[Unable to reach a break point in Javascript inspite of writing debugger- Visual studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338546/unable-to-reach-a-break-point-in-javascript-inspite-of-writing-debugger-visual)

Comment: I hope the answer in the above link exactly addresses your problem